# How can i get smooth framer motion animations on my navbar?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, animation, frontend, framer-motion

Im trying to learn framer motion I'm slowing trying to incorporate animations to my website however i have been struggling with this effect. I essentially want to have a fixed position navbar appear once I scroll past the 'hero' section of my website. If im on the hero then ill just the regular navbar similar to this navbar effect on [stripes](https://stripesessions.com/) ssession website. As you can see once you scroll past the main title page a floating navbar appears.

The issue I'm having is that currently my animation is not smooth of very 'responsive'.

1. The navbar just suddenly appears / disappears (no intro / outro animation)
2. There's significant lag, if I scroll too quickly the navbar appears halfway through my next section, or remains if i scroll to quickly back up to my hero section. (I understand there will be some delay but it feels very off)

Im not sure whats going wrong - any help would be greatly appreciated !

Here is my hero section:

```js
'use client';

import { useInView, motion, AnimatePresence, useAnimationControls } from 'framer-motion';
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import FloatingNavbar from './FloatingNavbar';

const myVariants = {
    hidden: { y: 75, opacity: 0 },
    visible: { y: 0, opacity: 1 },
};

function Hero() {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
    const inView = useInView(ref);
    const controls = useAnimationControls();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (inView) {
            controls.start('hidden');
        } else {
            controls.start('visible');
        }
    }, [inView]);

    return (
        <>
            <AnimatePresence>
                <motion.div
                    variants={myVariants}
                    initial="hidden"
                    exit="hidden"
                    animate={controls}
                    transition={{ duration: 0.5, ease: 'easeInOut', type: 'spring' }}
                >
                    <FloatingNavbar />
                </motion.div>
            </AnimatePresence>

            <section
                id="home"
                ref={ref}
                className="flex min-h-screen w-full flex-col items-center justify-center px-8 pt-16 md:flex-row md:justify-between md:px-16"
            >
                <div className="mb-8 max-w-lg text-center md:mb-0 md:text-left">
                    <h1 className="mb-4 text-4xl font-bold">Welcome to My Website</h1>
                    <p className="text-lg">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam auctor, nisl eget
                        ultricies lacinia, nisl nisl aliquam nisl, nec aliquam nisl nisl sit amet nisl.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div className="h-64 w-full md:w-1/2">
                    {/* Replace this div with your actual image */}
                    <div className="h-full w-full bg-gray-300"></div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </>
    );
}

export default Hero;
```

and heres my navbar:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ContactUsButton from '../ContactUsButton';

const navLinks = [
    { href: '#protocol', label: 'PROTOCOL' },
    { href: '#milestone', label: 'MILESTONES' },
    { href: '#contact', label: 'ABOUT US' },
];

const FloatingNavbar = () => {
    return (
        <header className="fixed left-1/2 top-0 flex min-w-[62rem] -translate-x-1/2 transform items-center justify-center">
            <nav className="glassy container relative mx-10 mt-6 flex items-center justify-between rounded-sm">
                <ul className="flex items-center p-2">
                    {navLinks.map(({ href, label }) => (
                        <li className="px-4" key={href}>
                            <a key={href} href={href} className="block rounded font-medium text-black ">
                                {label}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
                <div className="pr-4">
                    <ContactUsButton />
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    );
};

export default FloatingNavbar;
```